# How can I convert a column of Hex into text in SAS?

Tags: text, char, sas, hex, type-conversion

I have a column of raw text that is formatted as $hex2500. in SAS. How would I convert this data back into a long character string?

EDIT:
My data is saved like this: 54484953204953204558414d504c452044415441210d0a

Comment: Do you mean that the string contains combinations of the 16 characters 0-9 and A-F?  If so then use the INPUT() function with $HEX informat to convert.  But if you mean that the string contains binary data with $HEX format attached to it so that it displays as hexcodes then just use a different format to have it treat the values are character codes.

Comment: Thanks Tom, my data is in the first category. The INPUT() function with the $HEX informat works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this:

```
DATA NEW_DATA;
SET OLD_DATA;
text_formatted_string = INPUT(hex_formatted_string, $hex2500.);
RUN;
```